# Error in importing sample events for PredictioIO Universal Recommender

Tags: predictionio

I've installed PredictionIO 0.9.6 with ElasticSearch and HBase and then followed the instructions to use the UR template here: https://templates.prediction.io/PredictionIO/template-scala-parallel-universal-recommendation

When I try to import sample events by running 
`python examples/import_handmade.py --access_key **my-access-key**` 
I get this error:

> 401 body: {"message":"Invalid accessKey."}

The access key comes from `pio app list` command...

I tried also to upgrade the UR template to version 0.3.0 as suggested for other problems: deleted the directory with the template and reinstalled with git https://github.com/actionml/template-scala-parallel-universal-recommendation but when I run the `./examples/integration-test` I get the same error.

Anyone with this problem?

Comment: you're not putting quotes or <> signs around the access key are you?

Comment: No @alex9311, I pass it after the --access_key argument as it is.

Comment: what about going through curl? curl -i -X GET "http://localhost:7070/events.json?accessKey=$ACCESS_KEY"

Comment: Retrieving data is working, it's the import that doesn't work...

Comment: I have been getting the same error on running `./examples/integration-test`

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problems when running:

```
./examples/integration-test
```

or

```
python examples/import_handmade.py --access_key **my-access-key**
```

On reading the `pio.log` under the `~/ur` directory, I found that the access key was not being saved into DB (POSTGRES).

pio.log was showing that the `SELECT` query was failing.
So, I manually inserted the access key and App id into the DB.

After which the intergration test ran successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Had this too. Try running **without** exporting JAVA_HOME in hbase_site.xml (just skip that step) and only export JAVA_HOME in your environment.

Answer (score 0):

i use docker for predictioIo and get same error , i've just restart it and create a new app and try again and now i can import my data.

Answer (score 0):

**Reason for error**

The error happens generally when key stored on the eventserver is different from the key you are passing as argument.

In PIO, by default PIO eventserver run on port `7070`. 
So  this can happen if this port is already in use by some previous eventserver you started or by some other service.

Inside universal-recommender or your template directory, you can check the eventserver logs ( `pio.log or nohup.out` ). You will see error like

```
[INFO] [Management$] Creating Event Server at 0.0.0.0:7070
[WARN] [HttpListener] Bind to /0.0.0.0:7070 failed
[ERROR] [TcpListener] Bind failed for TCP channel on endpoint [/0.0.0.0:7070]
[ERROR] [EventServerActor] Command failed.
```

**Solution**

1) Check if port 7070 is occupied by some other service or by previous eventserver already

```
sudo ss -lptn 'sport = :7070'
```

Result `users:(("java",pid=16659,fd=45))`

2) Kill the service which is using that port ( 7070 )

```
kill -9 16659
```

3) Restart eventserver ( use `&` at the and of the command to run the command in background )

```
nohup pio eventserver
```

or

```
pio eventserver
```

You will see this output in the `console` or `nohub.out` file

```
[INFO] [Management$] Creating Event Server at 0.0.0.0:7070
[INFO] [HttpListener] Bound to /0.0.0.0:7070
[INFO] [EventServerActor] Bound received. EventServer is ready.
```